# Question about Singular $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Let's consider a $2\times 2$ singular matrix that maps every vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ into a line in $\mathbb{R^2}$.
Why we are sure that the map represented by this matrix is NOT injective ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that both $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$ belong to the same line. Therefore, there is some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(1,0)=\lambda f(0,1)$ (unless $f(0,1)=0$ and $f(1,0)\neq0$, but then it follows from the equality $f(0,1)=0$ that $f$ is not injective). Therefore, $f(1,-\lambda)=f\bigl((1,0)-\lambda(0,1)\bigr)=0$ and so $f$ is not injective.

Answer (score 1):

[Rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

In particular, a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$ is injective if and only if it has rank $m$. The rank is the dimension of the range, in this case $1$.